# Problema Drag and Drop y eliminar lo arrastrado

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando implementar que al arrastrar elementos del contenido de un carro de compra hacia un icono de papelera el elemento que arrastro se elimine al soltarlo sobre dicho icono. No tengo muy claro si se puede hacer ya que en la función de soltar, el evento lo captura el icono y pierdo el target del div que arrastro. Adjunto el código HTML y js que estoy usando:

```
<div class="elementos">
 <div>
    <div class="item" draggable="true" ondragstart="fase1(event);">
            <div class="div_nombre_item">
                <p class="nombre_item">${itemTitle}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cantidad_item">
                <input type="number" value="1" class="item_cantidad">
            </div>
            <div class="precio_item">
                <p class="dinero_total">${itemPrice}</p>
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div>
      <div class="item" draggable="true" ondragstart="fase1(event);">
            <div class="div_nombre_item">
                <p class="nombre_item">${itemTitle}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cantidad_item">
                <input type="number" value="1" class="item_cantidad">
            </div>
            <div class="precio_item">
                <p class="dinero_total">${itemPrice}</p>
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="basura">
        <span class="material-icons" id="icono_basura"  ondragover="fase2(event);" ondrop="fase3(event);">delete</span>
</div>
```

Codigo js:

```
function fase1(pEvento) {
    pEvento.dataTransfer.setData("", pEvento.target.className);
    console.log(pEvento.currentTarget.parentNode.className);//Aqui me saca
}



function fase2(pEvento) {
    pEvento.preventDefault();
}


function fase3(pEvento) {
    pEvento.preventDefault();
    console.log(elementoArrastrado.target.tagName); //Aqui me da undefined
    var datos = pEvento.dataTransfer.getData("");
    console.log(pEvento.target.id); //Aqui me saca el id del icono
}
```

La idea es que al arrastrar un div con clase="item" si lo suelto sobre el icono el div padre del div que he arrastrado se elimine.

Answer (score 1):

La clase ayuda poco para identificar el elemento a quitar, mejor usa su identificador, indicado como texto plano:

```js
function fase1(pEvento) {
    pEvento.dataTransfer.setData( "text/plain"
                                , pEvento.target.id
                                );
}

function fase2(pEvento) {
    pEvento.preventDefault();
}

function fase3(pEvento) {
    pEvento.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById( pEvento.dataTransfer.getData("text") )
            .remove();
    
}
```

```html
<div class="elementos">
 <div>
    <div class="item" draggable="true" ondragstart="fase1(event);" id="item1">
            <div class="div_nombre_item">
                <p class="nombre_item">${itemTitle}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cantidad_item">
                <input type="number" value="1" class="item_cantidad">
            </div>
            <div class="precio_item">
                <p class="dinero_total">${itemPrice}</p>
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div>
      <div class="item" draggable="true" ondragstart="fase1(event);" id="item2">
            <div class="div_nombre_item">
                <p class="nombre_item">${itemTitle}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cantidad_item">
                <input type="number" value="1" class="item_cantidad">
            </div>
            <div class="precio_item">
                <p class="dinero_total">${itemPrice}</p>
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="basura">
        <span class="material-icons" id="icono_basura"  ondragover="fase2(event);" ondrop="fase3(event);">delete</span>
</div>
```